# Maven - No versions available for junit:junit-dep:jar:[4.9,) within specified range

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm using the `system-rules` library to inject environment variables as part of my tests. This works great locally but Maven rejects the build on deployment within the CI/CD environment with the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on ABC: Could not resolve dependencies for project ABC: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.stefanbirkner:system-rules:jar:1.19.0 -> junit:junit-dep:jar:[4.9,): No versions available for junit:junit-dep:jar:[4.9,) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my dependency XML:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
            <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Where am I going wrong? I've googled alot, tried switching up the order etc but no luck. Thanks for help!

Comment: simply because junit:junit-dep only is available as version 4.11 see https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:junit-dep

Comment: But 4.11 should be in the range `[4.9,)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I've added that dependency which doesn't appear to have helped.